# How to return an error with JavaScript when someone enter just space on name field in a array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation

Here is a code for finding the largest word from an array. But When I input some space (`"        "`) like this I get the blank one as largest. But I want if anyone entered some space only it will return an error.
Can anyone tell me how to do that?

```js
function megaFriend(str) {
  var wordLength = 0;
  var biggestWord;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i].length > wordLength) {
      var wordLength = str[i].length;
      biggestWord = str[i];
    }
  }
  return biggestWord;
}

console.log(megaFriend(['Nahid', 'Hassan', 'Ahugoggghs', '                ']));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use str.replaceAll() method

```
let spaceFreeElement = str[i].replaceAll(" ", "");
```

or regex

```
let spaceFreeElement = str[i].replace(/\s/g, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to `String.trim()` the words when you check the length:

```js
function megaFriend(str) {
  var wordLength = 0;
  var biggestWord;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i].trim().length > wordLength) {
      var wordLength = str[i].length;
      biggestWord = str[i];
    }
  }
  return biggestWord;
}

console.log(megaFriend(['Nahid', 'Hassan', 'Ahugoggghs', '                ']));
```

You can also trim and throw an error if the string's length is 0 after trimming:

```js
function megaFriend(str) {
  var wordLength = 0;
  var biggestWord;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(str[i].trim().length === 0 && str[i].length > 0) {
      throw new Error(`illegal string - index ${i}`);
    }
  
    if (str[i].length > wordLength) {
      var wordLength = str[i].length;
      biggestWord = str[i];
    }
  }
  return biggestWord;
}

console.log(megaFriend(['Nahid', 'Hassan', 'Ahugoggghs', '                ']));
```

Comment: still getting the blank space as largest 
https://prnt.sc/xgk9b7

Comment: Try now. I've removed the trim by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to test if a word is just spaces, and report an error.

```js
function megaFriend(str) {
  var wordLength = 0;
  var biggestWord;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i].match(/^\s+$/)) {
      alert("Spaces entered");
      return false;
    }
    if (str[i].length > wordLength) {
      var wordLength = str[i].length;
      biggestWord = str[i];
    }
  }
  return biggestWord;
}

console.log(megaFriend(['Nahid', 'Hassan', 'Ahugoggghs', '                ']));
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the space. I just want to show them an error that they've enterted  a wrong input.

Comment: I've updated it to just check for spaces.

Comment: Thanks man. Take love ❤ .